# How to deal with multiple authors in one paper using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

So I am having troubles on how to implement multiple authors in one paper and how to separate authors to be used for citations of a paper.

currently I have my input like this

```
<div class="group">      
                                <input class="inputchecker2 inputInfo" id="inputID" type="text" name="Authors" required>
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label class="infoLabel">Author(s)</label>
                            </div>
```

where name="Authors" is stored like this in the controller

```
$paper=new Papers();

$paper->Authors=$request->Authors;
```

The problem arises once there are multiple authors in one paper and I don't know how to implement that and make it work I tried making another table for it but I got stuck in thinking of the Logic

my migration files is as follows:
PAPERS TABLE

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('papers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('PaperID');
            $table->string('PaperTitle');
            $table->string('PaperType');
            $table->string('Authors');
            $table->string('College')->nullable();
            $table->string('file');
            $table->date('DatePublished')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('UploaderUserID');
            $table->foreign('UploaderUserID')->references('UserID')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

AUTHORS TABLE

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('paper_authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('PaperAuthorID');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('paper_ID');
            $table->foreign('paper_ID')->references('PaperID')->on('papers');
            $table->string('AuthorName');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_ID');
            $table->foreign('user_ID')->references('UserID')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
```

Are there ways in simplifying this to make it easier for me to understand?

Comment: You have to create new table where author id and paper id exist. Then you have to make many to many relationship it work fine,

Comment: I've made a dummy test project, ive made a new table where those id exist but now the problem is that how do I assign the PaperID to an author when there are inputs text boxes when a user uploads a paper?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is kind of wrong from the start,

A paper can belong to multiple authors
An author can have multiple papers.

In your paper model, you should have this

```
    public function authors(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
```

In your author model, you should have this

```
    public function papers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Paper::class);
    }
```

Your Paper migration should look like this

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('author_papers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('college')->nullable();
            $table->string('file');
            $table->date('date_published')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Please note that I have changed some of the table columns to the Laravel convention (lowercase, snake_case instead of camelCase), the same will be done will the authors' table. I changed PaperIdD to id, I changed the table name to **author_papers** too. I made a lot of changes, check them and do what works for you. The important thing is to add `author_id` to the table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_ID')->references('UserID')->on('users');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

You don't need to add the paper id here, as one author can have many papers.

The last thing, a plus actually, when creating a new paper, you will need to send a list of all the authors to the HTML blade. So, the part the user will enter the author name will now be Select and not input again.

Best of success